# choosing from only one drop down box in php

Tags: php

I have two List Boxes and I click on both of them to create the SELECT query.I placed the $POST variable into another variable and then placed these into the select query.This seems to work fine,but the problem arises when I only want to select from one of the boxes for example just all of Ken Davis's books or all books from the adventure genre.It seems I have to chhose both boxes before I get a result.Can anyone suggest a way round this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form name="myform" action="dropdown2.php" method="POST">

<select name="author" size="4">
<option value="ken davies">ken davies</option>
<option value= "arthur smith">arthur smith</option>
<option value="gill rafferty">gill rafferty</option><br />
<option value="molly brown">molly brown</option><br />
<option value="gilbert riley">gilbert riley</option><br />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

<select name="genre" size="4"> 
<option value="adventure">adventure</option>
<option value="biography">biography</option>
<option value="crime">crime</option><br />
<option value="romance">romance</option>
<option value="2007">thriller</option>

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">


<?php

$_POST['author'];
$bird = $_POST['author'];
$_POST['genre'];
$cat = $_POST['genre'];


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
If (!$con){
    die("Can not Connect with database" .  mysql_error());
}
 Mysql_select_db("authors",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' AND genre = '$cat' ";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo"<table border=1>
<tr>id</th>
<tr>author</th>
<tr>title</th>
<tr>publisher</th>
<tr>year</th>
<tr>genre</th>
<tr>sold</th>
</tr>";


while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['author'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['publisher'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['genre'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['sold'] . "</td>";

    echo "<tr />";
}
echo "</table>";



mysql_close($con);



?>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by only author or only genre, change the logic leading up to your SQL.

```
if (isset($bird) && isset($cat))
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' AND genre = '$cat' ";
elseif (isset($bird))
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' ";
elseif (isset($cat))
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = '$cat' ";
```

Also I'm legally required to let you know that putting variables in SQL will lead to SQL injection. You should prepare and execute. I'll write some example code below (one sec).

Comment: many thanks to diggersworld,krish94 and Dave Chen for these great replies,they have all been most helpful..Dave... sql injection,I have heard about that but don't really understand it.Is it some sort of vunerability in the code?

Comment: @colin If `$bird` or `$cat` have single quotes, it will break your query. If you are happy with an answer here, feel free to accept it. Would you like to see a version of your code that is SQL-injection proof?

Comment: What happens if I have three drop down boxes?Would this code structure work?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the values from the form like you are doing, but you need to add in some code that allows them to be non-mandatory:

```
$bird = ( ! empty($_POST['author'])) ? $_POST['author'] : null;
$cat  = ( ! empty($_POST['genre']))  ? $_POST['genre']  : null;
```

This will either give you the value that was submitted with the form, or `null` which can be used later to decide how to query your db. I would also suggest you check the values given match what you expect. So either compare the data to known authors, or known genres and weed out tampered data, e.g:

```
$genres = array('adventure', 'biography', 'crime', 'romance', 'thriller');
if ( ! in_array($cat, $genres)) {
    // invalid data supplied (you could show an error)
    unset($cat); // destroys the invalid variable
}
```

Then when you come to your db query you can do something like this:

```
if (isset($bird) && isset($cat)) {
    // SELECT by both
}
else if (isset($bird)) {
    // SELECT by author
}
else if (isset($cat)) {
    // SELECT by cat
}
else {
    // SELECT all
}
```

There are many ways to shorten the above, but this is a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you will have to write separate queries in your PHP code for separate cases.

```
//When both the list boxes are selected
if(isset($_POST['author'])&&isset($_POST['genre']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' AND genre = '$cat' ";
    unset($_POST['genre']);
    unset($_POST['author']);
}
//When searching genre-wise (author variable not set)
elseif(!isset($_POST['author']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = '$cat' ";
    unset($_POST['genre']);
}
//When searching authorwise (genre variable not set)
elseif(!isset($_POST['genre']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird'";
    unset($_POST['author']);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the variables in PHP are carried over from the previous session and not automatically dumped/updated. It might thus lead to unwarranted results. Therefore, it's a good practice to unset the session variables or html elements before the end of the current session.

Comment: Hi Ikk,Thanks for the reply.Everything works fine but when I just click on one of the boxes(let's say authors) I get a reminder on my screen just above the table  like this......Notice: Undefined index: genre in C:\xampp\htdocs\dropdown2.php on line 32...and if I just click on genre I will get the same message but this time referring to authors.Is there a way around this.Many thanks ..col

Comment: I assume 
    `unset($_POST['genre']);`
   & `unset($_POST['author']);`  are generating error. I have updated my code. Kindly apply the changes.

Comment: Hi ikk,Many thanks you for the modification it works perfectly.Great!

Comment: if you've found your answer just hit the arrow beside the answer. happy to help!